# Trying to insert eml file as attachment gives error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character"

Tags: c#, email, base64, eml

I have a MailMessage in c# which I want to transform into an EML to insert as an attachment into another system, but the error I get is

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

textBody is not used.. I am only passing in html

```
public Task<string> CreateEml(string @from, string to, string subject, string htmlBody, string textBody, List<Attachment> attachments = null)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage())
        {               
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            message.From = new MailAddress(@from);
            //message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = htmlBody;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            if (attachments != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in attachments)
                {
                    message.Attachments.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBody))
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.Write(textBody);
                    message.AlternateViews.Add(new AlternateView(stream));
                    var eml = message.ToEml();
                    return Task.FromResult(eml);
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(message.ToEml());
        }
    }
```

There is an extension method ToEml() which does this

```
 public static string ToEml(this MailMessage message)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        var mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
            var mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);

            // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
            var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { memoryStream });

            // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
            var sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call method passing in MailWriter
            sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

            // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
            var closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call close method
            closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

This resulting data is assigned to data.EmailDataBus and used to insert the email as an attachment to a 3rd party system like this

```
attachment.FileInfo[0] = new FileInfoClass
            {
                Description = emailDescription,
                Category = "EMAIL",
                FileName = "NewBusiness.eml",
                Data = data.EmailDataBus,
            };

            using (var webService = new ConneXion())
            {
                webService.Url = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("tam.webservice.url");

                var response = webService.InsertAttachment(ref attachment);
```

The error message I get back is

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

The data in data.EmailBus looks like this, note I am not including all of the base64 but the header and footer is intact

https://plnkr.co/edit/n71EFK2gHRj6Nn4HX1Sn?p=preview

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: var response = webService.InsertAttachment(ref attachment);

Comment: Unless you have access to the internals for that web service, sounds like you need to contact ConneXion support, or at least consult the documentation. Maybe you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: Yea I will contact them first thing Monday, but based on the output in the link it doesnt seem there is any reason why it wouldnt be base64.

Comment: I dont have access to what InsertAttachment is doing, its an asmx web service. I will contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to encode the whole thing to base64.. which is a little odd as parts of the data already was base64 .. but I suppose not all of it. Anyway now it all works :) Attachment went in connexion fine.

```
byte[] emaildata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.EmailDataBus);
 string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(emaildata);
```